# Organizing docker images/containers/networks by folders or archives

Tags: docker

I built a few dozen Docker images, containers and networks in the course of a short programming project.  I can find them using `docker image ls`, `docker container ls --all`, etc.

Now I want to start a new, unrelated project, also using Docker.  I don't want to mix all my new project's images and containers with the old ones; I want a fresh start.

One option would be `docker prune`, but that's not quite right for me, as I want to be able to return to the old project later.

Is there any way to tell Docker to stash all my existing images/containers into a folder or archive? My best idea so far is to make a new VM for the new project, but I was hoping to find a simpler solution.

Answer (score 0):

If you’ve set everything up right, you should be able to delete everything now, making sure to keep any data directories around.  Later on you should be able to more or less

```sh
$SCM clone ...
cd myproject
cp -r $HOME/backups/myproject/mysql .
docker-compose up -d --build
```

For this to work:

- All of the artifacts you need to run the system — Dockerfiles, a `docker-compose.yml` or similar deployment control files, your application’s source, any config files — need to be checked into source control.
- You’ve never done `docker import` or `docker commit` or otherwise tried to create a container or image without going through the Dockerfile -> build -> run sequence.
- There’s no data that only lives in containers.  Anywhere a container happens to have persistent state it’s kept in either a named volume or a bind-mounted host directory.  (IMHO host directories are easier to back up and otherwise manage.)

This is the same set of step you need to do if you need to transplant your work on to a new system; you get a new shiny laptop; your colleague wants to start working on your project; your hard drive crashes and you need to start over; or `/var/lib/docker` just randomly corrupts itself.

Once you’re in this state, the containers don’t matter and you can just `docker stop && docker rm` them all (you have a scripted recipe to `docker run` or `docker-compose up` back into the same state).  Similarly, the images don’t matter and you can `docker rmi` everything (you can easily `docker build` from local source).